# Where does my native pointer go when I subtract to the BitmapData Scan0

Tags: pointers, f#

I thought that ofNativeInt was returning a pointer to a structure like a 1D array where all the image pixel data was stored. I was expecting the program throwing an exception after the first cycle but it doesn't instead it goes seemingly randomly until the null reference that I was expecting in the first cycle appears.

```
let Test (img : Bitmap) = 
    let bd = img.LockBits(Rectangle(0,0,img.Width,img.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    let mutable (pointer:nativeptr<byte>) = NativePtr.ofNativeInt (bd.Scan0)

    for i in 1 .. Int32.MaxValue do
        printf "%d : %d\n" i (NativePtr.get pointer 2)
        pointer <- NativePtr.add pointer -4
    done
```

Is the code accesing memory outside of its scope?

Comment: What is `p` in your above sample? Is it also a pointer? You appear to be interchanging `p` and `pointer` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are unsafe, normal out of bounds exceptions do not happen! If your lucky you'll hit a protected page and get an access violation exception, if not you'll just read whatever happens to be in memory at that pointer location.

Comment: Thank you, then the code is accessing some other variables allocated in the heap, right?

Comment: Suggested read: http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628  :-)

Comment: Well there isn't necessarily a variable allocated there, might just be empty heap space. The pointer might not even be pointing at the heap, you might of moved it into stack or data space. It's accessing something in memory and that's about all you can say about it.